# Passing dplyr filter conditions from shiny inputs into a function

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

I have been trying to create a general function to use in Shiny apps that will allow a dataframe to  be filtered by an arbitrary list of conditions using a sidebar menu.  So you can use the sidebar menu to pick both the columns you want to filter on and the conditions you wish to filter by.

Here is a trimmed down reproducible example of the Rmd that I have created which currently works for my purposes, using the mtcars dataset:

https://github.com/keithmcnulty/flexfiltering/blob/master/index.Rmd

Refer to my functions `filter1_by`, `filter2_by`, etc, built using `dplyr::filter_at` because I have to treat the column names differently from the values in non-standard evaluation.  This has forced me to have to create several functions depending on how many filters I want.  For example:

```
filter2_by <- function(df, f1, fv1, f2, fv2) {
  filter_f1 <- quo(f1)
  filter_f2 <- quo(f2)

df %>%
  dplyr::filter_at(vars(!!filter_f1), all_vars(. == fv1)) %>%
  dplyr::filter_at(vars(!!filter_f2), all_vars(. == fv2))
}
```

What I really want to do is just create a single function `filter_by(df, ...)` which will accept an arbitrary set of filter conditions, for example:

```
filter_by(mtcars, input$filter1 == input$filter1val, 
                  input$filter2 == input$filter2val)
```

Would love any advice on how to code `filter_by`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr` is not the only option to achieve your goal. With a simple Google search, it is possible to find many distinct ways to filter a data frame in R . In fact, the key to solving your problem here is the knowledge of the Shiny framework (i.e. return types, reactivity, etc) as you need to adapt any filtering method to your needs in the context.

Below is a concise Shiny example that includes everything you want. In addition to the filtering issue you stated, your code was very complicated. `updateSelectInput` will be your friend.

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "column",
    label = "Choose a column",
    choices = names(mtcars),
    selected = "mpg"
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "value",
    label = "Filter by:",
    choices = sort(mtcars$mpg),
    multiple = T
  ),
  htmlOutput(
    outputId = "table"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$column, {
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "value",
      choices = sort(mtcars[[input$column]]),
      selected = sort(mtcars[[input$column]])[1]
    )
  })
  output$table <- renderText({
    if(length(input$value) != 0) {
      kable(
        mtcars[mtcars[[input$column]] %in% as.numeric(input$value), ]
        ## just chain any additional conditions using &:
        # mtcars[
        #   mtcars[[input$column]] %in% as.numeric(input$value) &
        #   mtcars[[input$column2]] %in% as.numeric(input$value2) &
        #   mtcars[[input$column3]] %in% as.numeric(input$value3)
        # , ]
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative approach.  I will test it out for my needs.

Comment: Let me know if you have additional question and please accept the answer when you are convinced.